# Multiple conditional inserts with NodeJS, MySQL and Knex

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm developing a chat/messaging system in NodeJS that sends user input from a mobile app to a node server and then stores the users' messages in a MySQL database to be retrieved later. These messages can optionally contain either a media attachment (like audio or photos) or plain text.

So I've set it up with 2 basic tables for the messages: the 'chats' table and 'media_attachments' table. When a request comes in to the API at /chats via POST, I check whether the request body contains media or just text - if it contains media, I insert that data into the media_attachments table, then insert into the chats table using the foreign key media_attachment_id.

My question is, how do I handle an optional insert using the asynchronous nature of NodeJS? I'm coming from a PHP background, where the flow would be essentially:

```
media_attachment_id = 0;

if (media_content != null) {
  insert into media_attachments (media_content);
  media_attachment_id = last_insert_id;
}

insert into chats (data, media_attachment_id)
```

How do I handle the above with the promise-based flow of NodeJS and Knex?

Comment: Something like knex('media_attachments').insert(...).then(function (id) { knex('chats').insert(...)

Comment: @Molda yes but it's a conditional insert, the media_attachments insert only happens IF media_attachment_id != 0

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Then put chat insert in a function and use if statement like if(mediacontent){ knex insert and call chatInsert(id) from callback } else{ chatInsert() }